# Adding an column for the category of glm coeffients in broom results

Tags: r, glm, broom

Is there any way to add a column to the result of the broom package's `tidy` function that can act relate the term column back to both the original names used in the `formula` argument and their columns in the `data` argument.

For example if I run the following I get:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mod <- glm(mpg ~ wt + qsec + as.factor(carb), data = mtcars)

tidy(mod)

#               term     estimate std.error   statistic      p.value
# 1      (Intercept) 21.132995090 7.5756463  2.78959633 1.017187e-02
# 2               wt -4.916303175 0.6747590 -7.28601380 1.584408e-07
# 3             qsec  0.843355538 0.3930252  2.14580532 4.221188e-02
# 4 as.factor(carb)2  0.004133826 1.5321134  0.00269812 9.978695e-01
# 5 as.factor(carb)3 -0.755346006 2.3451222 -0.32209239 7.501715e-01
# 6 as.factor(carb)4 -0.489721798 2.0628564 -0.23739985 8.143615e-01
# 7 as.factor(carb)6 -0.886846134 3.4443957 -0.25747510 7.990068e-01
# 8 as.factor(carb)8 -0.894783610 3.7496630 -0.23863041 8.134180e-01
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
#               term     estimate std.error   statistic      p.value   term_base
# 1      (Intercept) 21.132995090 7.5756463  2.78959633 1.017187e-02 
# 2               wt -4.916303175 0.6747590 -7.28601380 1.584408e-07          wt
# 3             qsec  0.843355538 0.3930252  2.14580532 4.221188e-02        qsec
# 4 as.factor(carb)2  0.004133826 1.5321134  0.00269812 9.978695e-01        carb
# 5 as.factor(carb)3 -0.755346006 2.3451222 -0.32209239 7.501715e-01        carb
# 6 as.factor(carb)4 -0.489721798 2.0628564 -0.23739985 8.143615e-01        carb
# 7 as.factor(carb)6 -0.886846134 3.4443957 -0.25747510 7.990068e-01        carb
# 8 as.factor(carb)8 -0.894783610 3.7496630 -0.23863041 8.134180e-01        carb
```

Not so bothered if the first row in this new column is empty, `Intercept` or `1`. Just need something that can match the term column to the original variable names passed to the formula?

**Edit**

Would be good if it didn't depend on using `as.factor` in the formula, e.g. would work on:

```
mod <- glm(mpg ~ wt + qsec + carb, data = mtcars %>% mutate(carb = factor(carb)))

tidy(mod)

#          term     estimate std.error   statistic      p.value
# 1 (Intercept) 21.132995090 7.5756463  2.78959633 1.017187e-02
# 2          wt -4.916303175 0.6747590 -7.28601380 1.584408e-07
# 3        qsec  0.843355538 0.3930252  2.14580532 4.221188e-02
# 4       carb2  0.004133826 1.5321134  0.00269812 9.978695e-01
# 5       carb3 -0.755346006 2.3451222 -0.32209239 7.501715e-01
# 6       carb4 -0.489721798 2.0628564 -0.23739985 8.143615e-01
# 7       carb6 -0.886846134 3.4443957 -0.25747510 7.990068e-01
# 8       carb8 -0.894783610 3.7496630 -0.23863041 8.134180e-01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use regex to create the 'term_base' column

```
tidy(mod) %>%
        mutate(term_base = sub("Intercept", "", gsub(".*\\(|\\).*", "", term)))
#              term     estimate std.error   statistic      p.value term_base
#1      (Intercept) 21.132995090 7.5756463  2.78959633 1.017187e-02          
#2               wt -4.916303175 0.6747590 -7.28601380 1.584408e-07        wt
#3             qsec  0.843355538 0.3930252  2.14580532 4.221188e-02      qsec
#4 as.factor(carb)2  0.004133826 1.5321134  0.00269812 9.978695e-01      carb
#5 as.factor(carb)3 -0.755346006 2.3451222 -0.32209239 7.501715e-01      carb
#6 as.factor(carb)4 -0.489721798 2.0628564 -0.23739985 8.143615e-01      carb
#7 as.factor(carb)6 -0.886846134 3.4443957 -0.25747510 7.990068e-01      carb
#8 as.factor(carb)8 -0.894783610 3.7496630 -0.23863041 8.134180e-01      carb
```

---

The `as.factor` can be removed from the 'term' as well if we `mutate` the 'carb' to `factor` before the `glm` step

```
mtcars %>%
     mutate(carb = factor(carb)) %>% 
     glm(formula = mpg ~wt + qsec + carb, data = .) %>% 
     tidy(.) %>%
     mutate(term_base = sub("\\(.*\\)|\\d+", "", term))
#     term     estimate std.error   statistic      p.value term_base
#1 (Intercept) 21.132995090 7.5756463  2.78959633 1.017187e-02          
#2          wt -4.916303175 0.6747590 -7.28601380 1.584408e-07        wt
#3        qsec  0.843355538 0.3930252  2.14580532 4.221188e-02      qsec
#4       carb2  0.004133826 1.5321134  0.00269812 9.978695e-01      carb
#5       carb3 -0.755346006 2.3451222 -0.32209239 7.501715e-01      carb
#6       carb4 -0.489721798 2.0628564 -0.23739985 8.143615e-01      carb
#7       carb6 -0.886846134 3.4443957 -0.25747510 7.990068e-01      carb
#8       carb8 -0.894783610 3.7496630 -0.23863041 8.134180e-01      carb
```

Comment: Oh my gosh.Your answering my edit before I finished typing it. Many thanks.